# React why is this simple array map function not returning anything?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have a React component creating a bulleted list for items in an array (called activePath). The array is reporting correctly via console.log, and here is the format:

```js
{device_id: "nlab5320a", port_id: "XGigabitEthernet0/0/3"}
```

There are six of these in the array. I did an Array.isArray just to confirm that this is a true array and it is. I am trying to map this array and output a bulleted list with the following:

```js
activePath.map((item, i) => (
  <li key={i}>{item.device_id}</li>
));
```

Here is the entire component ...

```js
export default class ServicesInfo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { activePath } = this.props;
    const runTable = activePath.map((item, i) => (
      <li key={i}>{item.device_id}</li>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{runTable}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The ServicesInfo is the child component. Here is the parent ...

```
   export default class InfoHolder extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props) {
    }
render() {
  return(
     <div>
       <p>Here is a listing of the nodes:</p>
       <ServicesInfo />
     </div>
    )
  }
```

A single bullet with no text is returning. I have been at this project for about 16 hours straight and think I am just missing something simple. Please help!

Comment: this code you have written inside render function or inside a separate function component.

Comment: Could you please include your entire component? The code currently in your question isn't enough to say what might be wrong.

Comment: I am running it in the render function with  const runTable = activePath.map((item,i) =>
      <li key={i}>{item.device_id}</li>
    ) and calling it in the return with {runTable}

Comment: That's not enough either, sadly. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: I just added the component in my post. Thank you!

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this much piece of code. Please provide the part where you are using ServicesInfo.

Comment: Added the parent component in the original post.

Comment: You have not passed any `props` to `ServicesInfo` in you code snippet above. Therefore `this.props.activePath` is always `undefined` inside your `ServicesInfo` component.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your array in the component.
Also add `constructor(props){
  super(props) {}` to get props from other components.

```
export default class InfoHolder extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props) {
  this.state={
objectArray =[{device_id: "nlab5320a", port_id: "XGigabitEthernet0/0/3"}]     
}
    }
render() {
  return(
     <div>
       <p>Here is a listing of the nodes:</p>
       <ServicesInfo activePath={this.state.object} />
     </div>
    )
  }


    export default class ServicesInfo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
          super(props) {
        }

  render() {
    const { activePath } = this.props;
    const runTable = activePath.map((item, i) => (
      <li key={i}>{item.device_id}</li>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{runTable}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `InfoHolder` you haven't passed `activePath` as a prop to the `ServicesInfo` component. You have to pass the `activePath` like this: `<ServicesInfo activePath={activePath} />`

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9yn778zp4w)